# Change layout of legend2 in plotly

Tags: python, plotly, legend

How to change layout of legend2 with fig.update_layout()?

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
numbers = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4], [2,3,4,5], [5,7,8,8]])
asdf = px.line(numbers)
asdf = asdf.add_scatter(
    x=[4,3],
    y=[1,2],
    legend="legend2"
)
asdf = asdf.update_layout(
    legend_font=dict(size=20),
    legend2_font=dict(size=20),
)
asdf
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "magic underscore" notation doesn't fully work when updating `layout.legend2`, because there is no (default for) `legend2` in the layout, even it is referenced by one of the scatter traces (unlike with axes, eg. a reference to `'x2'` will make plotly defines `layout.xaxis2`).

So to make it work you need to define `legend2` as a dictionary, under that key you can use underscore shortcuts :

```py
asdf.update_layout(
    legend_font_size=20,
    legend2=dict(font_size=20, y=0.8)
)
```